# How to show/hide components based on a selected item in Vue

Tags: vue.js

What I want to achieve:

First, I want to make the "Select" component visible if its related value is chosen from Main Select.
Secondly, I want to hide the "Select" component and make the Input Field visible if its related value is chosen from Main Select.

I tried something but the "Select" component is created more than once whenever I choose its related value from Main Select.

What I have tried:

```
**This is Main Select and it has two values.
The first one should make the other "Select" Component visible
The second one should make InputField visible and hide "Select" Component**
                     
<select 
v-select class="form-control" 
v-model="form.institutionType"                  
@change="change">
    <option :value="null">Choose One</option>
    <option :value="item.Id"
    v-for="(item,index) in $store.state.inspection.institutionTypeP" :key="index">
        {{ item.Text }}
    </option>
</select>
```

The below code is for "Select" Component and Input Field:

```
<select v-select class="form-control" v-model="form.linkedDepartment" v-if ="connectedUnit===True" >
    <option :value="null">Choose One</option>
    <option :value="item.id"
    v-for="(item,index) in linkedDepartments" :key="index">
        {{ item.Text}}
    </option>
</select>

 <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="form.dossierNo" v-if="connectedUnit===false">
```

Finally, script part; for the "change" function

```
change() {
    if(this.form.institutionType===1 ){
        this.connectedUnit = true;
    }
    else{
        this.connectedUnit = false;
    }            
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that I've noticed in your code is that in the select and input that you want to hide and show, you have used with the `<select>` - `v-if="connectedUnit===True`
The **True** in this should be in lowercase i.e. `v-if="connectedUnit===true`

Other than this, I tried your code and it was working as you want it to.

What I did:

In the `<template>` tag:

```
<select v-select class="form-control" v-model="form.institutionType" @change="change">
  <option :value="null">Choose One</option>
  <option :value="item.Id" v-for="(item,index) in institutionTypeP" :key="index">
        {{ item.Text }}
    </option>
</select>

<select v-select class="form-control" v-model="form.linkedDepartment" v-if ="connectedUnit===true" >
    <option :value="null">Choose One</option>
    <option :value="item.id"
    v-for="(item,index) in linkedDepartments" :key="index">
        {{ item.Text}}
    </option>
</select>

<input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="form.dossierNo" v-if="connectedUnit===false">
```

And in the `<script>` tag:

```
change() {
    if(this.form.institutionType===1 ){
        this.connectedUnit = true;
    }
    else{
        this.connectedUnit = false;
    }            
},
```

With the above code, when the first option is selected from the main select, then the select is shown, and when the second option is selected from the main select, then the input field is shown.

[image]
And
[image]

If yours still doesn't work, then there may be something with the data that you're using...
The data I used is as follows:

```
data()
{
    return {
        connectedUnit: true,
        form: { institutionType: 1, linkedDepartment: 2, dossierNo: null },
        institutionTypeP: [ { Id: 1, Text: 'One' }, { Id: 2, Text: 'Two' } ],
        linkedDepartments: [ {Text: '1'}, {Text: '2'} ]
    }
},
```

All is same as your code, but I just used an **institutionTypeP** list instead of **$store.state.inspection.institutionTypeP**